# Update Query not working. Always catch syntax is running

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, razor

I want to update a record. But every time i tried to update. It goes to catch statement. I am unable to find that where my query syntax is invalid.

**It always goes to catch statement**

I have no idea that either the query is wrong or any error is in the syntax.

```
   if (IsPost) {
    var value = Request.Form["value"];
    var Student_Reg_No = Request.Form["Student_Reg_No"];
    var Student_Name = Request.Form["Student_Name"];
    var Father_Name = Request.Form["Father_Name"];
    var Temporary_Address = Request.Form["Temporary_Address"];
    var Permanent_Address = Request.Form["Permanent_Address"];
    var Phone_No = Request.Form["Phone_No"];
    var Blood_Group = Request.Form["Blood_Group"];
    var Email_Address = Request.Form["Email_Address"];

    if (Validation.IsValid()){
        try{
            var db = Database.Open("site_data");
            var updateCommand = "Update site_data_table set Student_Reg_No =@0, Student_Name=@1, Father_Name=@2, Temporary_Address=@3,Permanent_Address=@4, Phone_No=@5, Blood_Group=@6, Email_Address=@7 where Id=@8)";
            db.Execute(updateCommand, Student_Reg_No, Student_Name, Father_Name, Temporary_Address, Permanent_Address, Phone_No, Blood_Group, Email_Address, value);
            Response.Redirect("~/edit?id=success");
        }
        catch{
            <textarea>Data is Not updated</textarea>
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Capture exception in catch clause and see details.Post here if it's unreadable to you.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Please explain more about your problem with details.

Comment: could you comment `Response.Redirect` and cross check ?

Answer (score 1):

```
           var updateCommand = "Update site_data_table set Student_Reg_No =@0, Student_Name=@1, Father_Name=@2, Temporary_Address=@3,Permanent_Address=@4, Phone_No=@5, Blood_Group=@6, Email_Address=@7 where Id=@8)";
```

Change to

```
       var updateCommand = "Update site_data_table set Student_Reg_No =@0, Student_Name=@1, Father_Name=@2, Temporary_Address=@3,Permanent_Address=@4, Phone_No=@5, Blood_Group=@6, Email_Address=@7 where Id=@8";
```